# Getting the inserted id MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to get the last inserted id in MySQL

easiest way is to use `$mysqli->insert_id;` My question is is this the best way to do it?

What if another user insert another post at the same and will it give a wrong id?

Appropriate any comments.

Comment: yes this is the only way. Dont worry about insertion in same time. mysql manage it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This id is related to connection added by $mysqli and is not related to another user

Comment: thank you for your answer. Have one more question do i need to run another query to get the other details from the database or is there another way to get all the details of the table along with the last inserted it?

Comment: for getting data related to last inserted id you need to run another query where in where condition look like  'WHERE  id = ".$lastid."'

Comment: in this case you just need to have insert id, because you have information which you inserted :-), if you are force you should run query with inserted id

Comment: @MajidAbbasi Abbas yes you are correct. didn't think of that. Thank you for your help sir. Really appropriated.